How to make nextjs build error log more sense?
Is there an option in nextjs to make build logs more understandable?
If build has an error, log shows chunk path, but I like to see exact file path, where error occured and line number. If there is error because of request error I'd like to see exact request url and response error code and message.
Is it possible to make logs with such information?
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at supportUrl (/app/.next/server/chunks/5449.js:153:45)
    at new BillingAbstract (/app/.next/server/chunks/8753.js:222:89)
    at new ProfileBilling (/app/.next/server/chunks/5506.js:165:1)
    at d (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:320)
    at bb (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at Object.renderPage (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:680:46)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:350:67)

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
    at /app/.next/server/chunks/2996.js:5148:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async getStaticProps$1 (/app/.next/server/pages/legal/[key]/[documentId]/archive.js:66:21)
    at async renderToHTML (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:386:20)
    at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:304:36
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
Error occurred prerendering page "/ru/legal/4game/2944/archive". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Warning: data for page "/legal/[key]/[documentId]/archive/[versionId]" (path "/legal/4game/33/archive/5575/") is 208 kB which exceeds the threshold of 128 kB, this amount of data can reduce performance.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/large-page-data
getStaticProps error:  {
  description: 'No data for key: Innova.Content.Application.Queries.Pages.GetPageQuery',
  code: 'content.datanotfound'
}
getStaticProps error:  {
  description: 'No data for key: Innova.Content.Application.Queries.Pages.GetPageQuery',
  code: 'content.datanotfound'
}

